# Is there anyway to integrate R highchart interactive plots in Latex? or to save them so that they are interactive?

Tags: r, highcharts, leaflet, latex

I am doing analysis and I have plotted some interactive plots using highcharts in r. But I want to integrate them in Latex so that they are interactive. 
I am making a report in Latex and I need those interactive plots.
Is there any way by which I can save them interactively? and plot them in Latex? 
Also, I have plotted a map using leaflet and I want that to be interactive in my pdf as well. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks.